# Do goji berries have thorns?

Tags: berries

The only place that I can find a reference to goji berries having thorns is on a reputable sellers website, but none of the big vidiographers mention anything about it. Do they have thorns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lycium barbarum*, the usual variety of goji berry, does have spines or thorns, mentioned under pruning and training in this link  https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=581 It suggests wearing gloves to protect against the spines.

Comment: it's a bad link

Comment: Try it now, I think the presence of a comma confused it, I've altered the text a little.

Comment: Link is good; And there are are illustrations of their thorns online.